# Where is Template Path Hints in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, template-hints

Just started playing about with Magento 2.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the "Template Path Hints" option that used to be in ***System > Configuration > Developer > Debug***?

Comment: Here is one extension in github which allows you to turn on the template path hints on the fly just by using query string(?tp=1): http://bit.ly/EasyTemplatePathHInts-Github

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can only see some settings in `developer mode`. So first of all check that you are in developer mode, if not then run this command `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` in `root` directory.

Then go to admin panel:

For Front End:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

---

For Admin :

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
>      Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes

Comment: I have enabled but not able to see hints on either frontend or admin dashboard

Comment: Note that this menu item is visible in developer mode only.
    php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: @rakesh can you please help me on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246502/magento-2-configurable-product-variation-dropdown-attribute-s-want-to-select-aut

Comment: I have followed your post which you have provide for by default selection for options while loading the page https://prnt.sc/l8xn28

Comment: Not sure this is still true for 2.2.6, and will use n98 command line option.

Comment: Does not work, the template hints do still not show

Comment: Note that you will need to add /?templatehints=magento at the end of your url in the browser

Answer (score 24):

**You can do it by two ways:**

1. Using cli:

goto you project root directory on command line and run below command

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable 

php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

2. go to admin backend:

   **Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes**

   **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes**

   **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Add Block Names to Hints > Yes**

[image]

Hope, this will help some extend.

Comment: [The CLI option was added in 2.2.0](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0EE.html)

Comment: Thanks  @Pramod Kharade, can you see the hints in production mode this way?

Answer (score 20):

Go to admin

**For Front End:**

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

**For Admin :**

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes

Answer (score 11):

If you use *n98-magerun2* script from https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Run the following from website root to enable hints

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints --on
```

And this to disable

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints --off
```

Comment: enable / disable is not a valid argument to pass, therefore will not do as you have described. The function will toggle without that argument. The correct argument to pass is the store code. https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#template-hints

Comment: Technically it is correct, the store code `default` is added by... default. :) and in situations where admin is needed, `admin` is used. Majority of  stores are usually running one store view/website. n98-magerun does a good job detecting your default view also: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/blob/880b7a675028ca6d12c0b41854e3951c5d73eacd/src/N98/Magento/Command/AbstractMagentoStoreConfigCommand.php#L104-L134 If you're trying to only target a non-default store code, then yes the argument would be required, but without still technically *NOT* invalid.

Answer (score 8):

If you are connected to database, you can enable by running below query,

**For Frontend:**

```
update core_config_data set value = 1 where path = 'dev/debug/template_hints_storefront'
```

**For Admin:**

```
update core_config_data set value = 1 where path = 'dev/debug/template_hints_admin'
```

**Flush Cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush OR 
php bin/magento cache:clean OR
From admin flush cache
```

Comment: this is not in magento2

Comment: This will work for  Magento 2  as well. please check `SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%dev/debug%'`

Comment: Magento <2.2 doesn't have `dev:template-hints:[enable,disable]`, so this is what you need to use from CLI for that version..

Answer (score 7):

With command line we can also disable/enable path hint in **Magento 2.2**

For Enable

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
```

For Disable

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't worry about using a free extension I'd suggest this one:

https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints

> **Ho_Templatehints extends the default Magento template hints.**
>
> - Easily accessible with with muscle memory `?ath=1`.
> - Shows hints for Templates, AbstractBlocks (Blocks), Containers and UI Components.
> - No layout interference: Using css outline instead of borders of other HTML elements, so it doesn't f'up the layout.

Not really an answer to the question, but hopefully useful if you work with template hints or want to debug layouts/templates.

Answer (score 1):

Open `vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php`

write this code inside `afterCreate` function : (at the start, above the storecode line)

```
if(isset($_GET['shreyasPathHints']) && $_GET['shreyasPathHints'] == 'on'){
    return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
        'subject' => $invocationResult,
        'showBlockHints' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Now, you can open any Magento page and append `?shreyasPathHints=on` to the URL. No need to run any commands.

**P.S. I strongly discourage this method. Only to be used on the local system.**

Answer (score 0):

As Magento 1 provided, similarly Magento 2 providing with additional Option "Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin"

Go to admin ->

Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug -> Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront -> Yes

Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug -> Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin -> Yes

Comment: Other answers already covered this way

Answer (score 0):

Several of these answers demonstrate use of parameter

This feature has been built into 2.3 for a little while now

Store > configuration > advanced > developer

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7aa94564d85e408baea01abc5315a0441401c375/app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L126-L133

```
                <field id="template_hints_parameter_value" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Parameter Value</label>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="*/*/template_hints_storefront">1</field>
                        <field id="*/*/template_hints_storefront_show_with_parameter">1</field>
                    </depends>
                    <comment>Add the following parameter to the URL to show template hints ?templatehints=[parameter_value]</comment>
                </field>
```