# How to get certain container template?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, magento-2.0

I can deal with layouts to move blocks and any action to be made over blocks in Magento 2. I can even modify templates for each block individually.

But, how can I modify a container block? I cannot find the template whose draws it. For example, the phtml file that draws the whole page container.

I need actually to find the header container that draws this:

```
<header class="page-header"><div class="magestore-bannerslider">
    </div>
<div class="header content"><span class="action nav-toggle" data-action="toggle-nav"><span>Nav de palanca</span></span>
    <strong class="logo">
        <img width="119" height="110" alt="Para Mi Casa" src="http://www.depasa.cl/pub/media/logo/default/logo-depasa.png">
    </strong>

<div class="minicart-wrapper" data-block="minicart">
    <a data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'" href="http://www.depasa.cl/checkout/cart/" class="action showcart">
        <span class="text">Mi carrito</span>
        <span data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading" class="counter qty empty">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>

        <script>
        window.checkout = {"shoppingCartUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/checkout\/cart\/","checkoutUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/checkout\/","updateItemQtyUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/checkout\/sidebar\/updateItemQty\/","removeItemUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/checkout\/sidebar\/removeItem\/","imageTemplate":"Magento_Catalog\/product\/image_with_borders","baseUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/","customerLoginUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/customer\/account\/login\/","isRedirectRequired":false,"autocomplete":"off","captcha":{"user_login":{"isCaseSensitive":false,"imageHeight":50,"imageSrc":"","refreshUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/captcha\/refresh\/","isRequired":false},"guest_checkout":{"isCaseSensitive":false,"imageHeight":50,"imageSrc":"","refreshUrl":"http:\/\/www.depasa.cl\/captcha\/refresh\/","isRequired":false}}};
    </script>

<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="ui-id-1"><div data-role="dropdownDialog" class="block block-minicart empty ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" style="display: block;">
            <div data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'" id="minicart-content-wrapper">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div></div></div>


<div class="block block-search">
    <div class="block block-title"><strong>Buscar</strong></div>
    <div class="block block-content">
        <form method="get" action="http://www.depasa.cl/catalogsearch/result/" id="search_mini_form" class="form minisearch">
            <div class="field search">
                <label data-role="minisearch-label" for="search" class="label">
                    <span>Buscar</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" maxlength="128" class="input-text" placeholder="Busque aquí en toda la tienda..." value="" name="q" id="search">
                    <div class="search-autocomplete" id="search_autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div class="nested">
    <a data-action="advanced-search" href="http://www.depasa.cl/catalogsearch/advanced/" class="action advanced">
        Búsqueda avanzada    </a>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action search" title="Buscar" type="submit" disabled="">
                    <span>Buscar</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="compare wrapper"><li data-role="compare-products-link" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" class="item link compare">
    <a data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}" title="Comparar productos" class="action compare no-display">
        Comparar productos        <span data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption" class="counter qty"></span>
    </a>
</li>

</ul><div class="panel header"><a href="#contentarea" class="action skip contentarea"><span>Ir al contenido</span></a>

<ul class="header links">        <li data-bind="scope: 'customer'" class="greet welcome">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '¡Bienvenido a Depasa!'"></span>
        </li>

    <li data-label="o" class="authorization-link">
    <a href="http://www.depasa.cl/customer/account/login/">
        Iniciar sesión    </a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.depasa.cl/customer/account/create/">Crear una cuenta</a></li></ul></div>
<nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
    <ul id="ui-id-2" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" tabindex="0">
        <li class="level0 nav-1 first last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a class="level-top ui-corner-all" href="http://www.depasa.cl/luz-para-el-hogar.html" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Luz para el hogar</span></a></li>    </ul>
</nav>
</div></header>
```

With that block, I have set the header to have the top links, the topmenu, the logo and the search module, but according to the design for my page, I need to change radically the HTML markup, since the containing div and below.

Any hints please?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Template Hints to tell you which .phtml template you need to edit. Magento 2 has this, the same as Magento 1 does, just in a different place in the admin. See this thread: [Where is Template Path Hints in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91235/where-is-template-path-hints-in-magento-2)