# How to display product discount percent on product details page in Magento 2.1.8?

Tags: magento-2.1

I don't know how to implement this task.This is my task screenshot.Please check my screenshot.[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to get % from special price ? i.e $45 normal price and $35 is special price. ?

Answer (score 1):

add following code will give percentage saving

```
<?php
$_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
$_price =$_product->getPrice();
if($_finalPrice < $_price):
   $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
          echo $_savingPercent; ?> % Off
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to add it on final_price.phtml

```
<?php
$_finalPrice =$block->getSaleableItem()->getFinalPrice(); 
$_price =$block->getSaleableItem()->getPrice();
if($_finalPrice < $_price):
 $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
        echo $_savingPercent; ?> % Off
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @ Qaisar Satti, where the code is added.Please tell me the file path.Can you please help me.

Comment: @DileepKumar enable the template path hint from admin panel. you will find your file. you can enable through lin https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91235/where-is-template-path-hints-in-magento-2

Comment: Hi @ Qaisar Satti, this code is not working.It generates this below error message.We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.
Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi @ Qaisar Satti,I have added the code path is C:\xampp7.0\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml file.It is correct?Can you please help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar check the latest code.

Comment: Hi, I am adding the code at the end of the file.Is it correct?

Comment: Hi @ Qaisar Satti, I have added your latest code no errors but nothing display saving percent in product details page.

Comment: Hi @ Qaisar Satti,Please check my screenshots https://prnt.sc/inzh3t https://prnt.sc/inzhqn

Comment: @DileepKumar wait for some minute i will give your complete solution that will not include the editing the core file.

Comment: Ok. I am waiting for your correct answer.

Comment: @DileepKumar added the tested solution.

Comment: Please send me the tested solution.

Comment: @DileepKumar `$_finalPrice =$block->getSaleableItem()->getFinalPrice(); 
       $_price =$block->getSaleableItem()->getPrice();
       if($_finalPrice < $_price):
         $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
                echo $_savingPercent; ?> % Off

     <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

could you pls advice which is correct place to add your piece of code?
I'm a bit confused because it has no php opening block like `<?php if` but have closing one...