# How to display product discount percent on product details page in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

Am I wondering how to add percentage discount value on the product details page?
I have found a similar topic, but apparently, it does not work with 2.2.1

[How to display product discount percent on product details page in Magento 2.1.8?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216306/how-to-display-product-discount-percent-on-product-details-page-in-magento-2-1-8)[image]

upd:[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you added special price for products ?

Comment: if you meant price rules - yes i did, it showed correctly (old and new price), but i'd like to show % which user will save.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show discount % on product detail page add below code where you want. This will show discount % either applied with **Catalog Price rule** or added **Special price**.

For example to show % near stock status add code in below template : 
**Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**.

```
<?php
$simplePrice = 0;
$_savingPercent = 0;
if($_product->getTypeId() == "simple") {
   $simplePrice = $_product->getPrice();
} else {
   $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
    $simplePrice = $child->getPrice();
    break;
   }
}

$_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice();
$_price = $simplePrice;
if($_finalPrice < $_price) {
   $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
   echo 'Your save '.$_savingPercent . '%';

}
?>
```

NOTE : assuming all simple products of configurable have same price , however condition will pick only first simple product price of configurable product and calculate discount. But this logic / code block can be altered depending on the requirements.

Comment: Naveed, thanks for reply, but not helped.
as i'm using standard luma theme, i have added it to 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml,
also to vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
no luck((
cache cleaned and reindexed of course. maybe redeploy content?

Comment: yes re deploy your static content, but it should work, unless you don't have created any custom theme having above files. as before posting solution  i had implemented on luma theme myself and it worked

Comment: unfortunately not helped... i have no custom theme, clean magento installation.
could you pls confirm exact path is vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml?
which magento version do you have? mine is 2.2.1

Comment: could you update the question with screen shot of your theme directory and where you are making changes.

Comment: have you added any special price ? also could you show me your theme files of Magneto_Catalog folder or you have not setup any theme yet ?

Comment: i have added screenshot with special price above. also i have no additional theme installed, it's clean magento installation. thanks!

Comment: right, but i don't see any special price added in above screenshot, the only reason if it is not working is only and if special price is not added otherwise it should work without any issue.

Comment: hmm, i guess we have serious misunderstanding here. what do we call "special price"? i thought it's Promo Price, which we set in Marketing -> Catalog price rule. Isn't it??

Comment: special price is always, which is setup in Advanced Pricing.. And Catalog Price rule is different, so do you want whichever is applied in discount rule should display in %, then this solution will not work

Comment: got it. but i cannot use Advanced Prices, it doesn't work for configurable products, only price rules...

Comment: i think modification should be inserted here:
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
but i cannot figure it out myself, so asking for help.

Comment: give me few minutes, i will update with right answer, which show discount % with respect to price rule

Comment: i have updated the answer, let me know if it works

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: How can I show discount for configurable product also. @Naveed.

Comment: @PranayK, where do you want to show this % this will show on product detail page. however you can check final_price.phtml file in module-configureable-product module.

Comment: I need to show the % discount for configurable product on list page @Naveed

Comment: I need to show the % discount for configurable product on product page. if Associate product price is different than discount should be different. I use above way this is working if price is same for products.

Comment: Configureable products don't have prices, it shows simple product price. And yes this code will work for all simple products if have same price otherwise you can add condition to check prices.

Answer (score 2):

To display the discount percentage in product view page.
Either you can override one of the below phtml.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml,
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

```
  $blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Price');
 $_product = $blockObj->getProduct();
    $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
       $price = $_product->getPrice();
    if ($price) {
       echo $sale = round(abs((($price-$specialprice)/$price)*100));
    }
```

Hope this will help !! Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

To display product discount Price use the below code.

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Price');

$_product = $blockObj->getProduct();
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
$today = time();
$price = $_product->getPrice();

if ($price) {
   echo $sale = round((($price-$specialprice)/$price)*100);
}
```

Comment: It will only work for simple product.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to get the discount amount

```
    public function getProductDiscount(ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();
        $finalPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()->getValue();

        if ($finalPrice < $regularPrice) {
            return round(100 - $finalPrice / $regularPrice * 100) . '%';
        }
    }
```