# Magento2: How to display always special price on configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

When I open **simple product** then I always see price and special price.
[image]

Issues is when I open configurable product then I see only special price:
[image]

When I choose "size" only then display price and special price:
[image]

I would like it to always display  price and special price regardless of whether I choose size or not.

Comment: you can check this post/answer and edit as per your need, you would see % of product but can edit to show special price : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219718/how-to-display-product-discount-percent-on-product-details-page-in-magento-2-2-1