# Path hints not displaying in frontend and admin in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento2.2

I don't know how to implement this task. In admin page, I have `stores->Configuration->Advanced->developer`

I have to choose to Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront "`yes`".
I have to choose to Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin "`yes`".

But in Front-end and admin not display path hints.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful to you, Up vote and accept as answer to help other who encounter same problems like you !!

Comment: Check with Vivek answer and it will not help then check my answer. I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I have post my answer please check one more configuration , it may be helpful to you to display template hints.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to **`developer mode`** in order to enable **Template Path Hints** for Frontend and Admin as well.

Related guide to enable **Template Path Hints** in Magento 2 Check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91235/where-is-template-path-hints-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Magento 2.2** then on **production mode**, the template hint will not work. You need to change it to developer mode and check below the things.

You need to set scope `Default store view` or your `current store view`. If You have set Main Website in Current configuration scope.

After setting Current configuration as Your Default store view and check Yes for storepath hints for front and Blockpath hints as `Yes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already doing configuration it means your are not in production mode.

First of all check configuration by store wise.

If it is okay then check one more configuration for developer restriction.

> go to stores->Configuration->Advanced->developer >Developer Client
>   Restrictions[image]

Be sure that there is no IP set in this configuration. if yes then remove it otherwise set your IP there and check scope from store view.

Answer (score 0):

To enable template path hints first you have to change your store view like below:

[image]

**Note:** If you are using multi store than you have to choose particular store view for ex: "English" or "French"

after that enter your IP address in below field:

> stores->Configuration->Advanced->developer >Developer Client Restrictions
>   [image]

After that choose Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront to "yes" and Save your configuration and clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-store site but switch to Single Store Mode, you may run into a problem I had - of being unable to change settings as the default store may no longer update core values. This meant I wasn't able to turn on hints using the admin UI.

What I had to do was go to the database & search for %hints% and find core_config_data rows where the template hints were set. I was then able to update the store where in my case the scope_id = 1, to set hints on or off.
[image: core_config_data template_hints]

Doing this I was able to turn hints on/off as required in the database rather than the admin UI.

This is related to this issue [product-updates-not-showing-on-front-end-store-scope-issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279935/magento2-product-updates-not-showing-on-front-end-store-scope-issue) which shows a fix for related problems possibly encountered when switching to Single Store Mode.