# Magento2 : Product Updates Not Showing on Front End - store scope issue

Tags: magento2, product-list, stock

**Problem**:
Certain product attribute updates are not being seen on the front end. Irrespective of re-indexing, cleaning and flushing the cache, etc.

If I change them via Update Mass Attributes, then that's ok, but not if I update each product individually. The update sticks but is not shown on the front end, nor in the product's Admin grid.

**Cause**:
Here's what I think has happened. The Magento 1.9 store had two websites, with products shared between both sites/stores. Some attributes (short description, etc) were maintained at a store level, others (SKU, etc) at the default level.

These were migrated to Magento 2.2.4 but then the decision was made to remove the second website. The decision was then to switch to Single Store Mode.

What I think has happened is that certain attributes like short description are now "set" to be udpated at store level scope -  but the Admin and the front end are showing "default" scope values. In Single Store Mode you can't see/change the "store" level attributes. Hence I can't see changes to the short description in the Admin product's grid nor on the front end.

**Solution**:
Is there a way to force all attributes back to the default store scope?

Any suggestions gratefully rec'd.

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what you are asking to do but...

Backup db before update

To set all product attribute values back to their default value which will be default admin scope

In database do the following

```sql
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE store_id <> 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime WHERE store_id <> 0;
```

To set attribute scope to global

```sql
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET is_global = 1 WHERE attribute_id = YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic - I'll give this a go next week & report back. Eddie

Comment: Hi Dominic - that worked a treat. Thanks again for your help.