# Magento 2 configurable product variation dropdown attribute/s want to select automatically, if it has single option?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, drop-downs

We have configurable product have some **drop down** attribute variations. here would like to choose by default when the attribute has **single** option in the product view page.

Can you please give me some suggestions?

[image: automatic selection]

**I found template file in the vendor:-**

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable*/
$_product    = $block->getProduct();
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <div class="field configurable required">
            <label class="label" for="attribute<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-selector="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select">
                    <option value=""><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Choose an Option1...') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar('gallery_switch_strategy',
                        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct') ?: 'replace'; ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

> pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js

```
_fillSelect: function (element) {
            var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
                options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
                prevConfig,
                index = 1,
                allowedProducts,
                i,
                j;

            this._clearSelect(element);
            element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
            element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
            prevConfig = false;

            if (element.prevSetting) {
                prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
            }

            if (options) {
                for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    allowedProducts = [];

                    /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                    if (prevConfig) {
                        for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                            // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                            if (prevConfig.config &&
                                prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                                prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                                allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
                    }

                    if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                        options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                        element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                        if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                            element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                        }

                        element.options[index].config = options[i];
                        index++;
                    }

                    /* eslint-enable max-depth */
                }

            }
        },
```

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom jquery to select first option automatically, when there is a single option, like below in phtml file :

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    if(jQuery('.super-attribute-select option').length == 1){
        jQuery('.super-attribute-select option:first').attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Manashvi Birla i will check and getback thanks for your reply

Comment: no @manashvi its not working

Comment: @NagarajuKasa - can you post the structure of the select box here. may some id is mismatch

Comment: https://prnt.sc/l6b1ga

Comment: @NagarajuKasa - check the updated ans. I have changed the class

Comment: No luck @ManashviBirla

Comment: @ManashviBirla I need help for swatch image first attribute with shows automatically please go through my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257577/magento2-how-to-remove-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-drop-down/258144?noredirect=1#comment363515_258144"

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy and pasted configurable.js from `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` to my custom theme `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js`
2. There is a method `_fillSelect: function` around 356 line number as per the requirement modified as below.

   ```
     /*** Populates an option's selectable choices.
        * @private
        * @param {*} element - Element associated with a configurable option.
        */
       _fillSelect: function (element) {
           var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
               options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
               prevConfig,
               index = 1,
               allowedProducts,
               i,
               j;

           this._clearSelect(element);
           element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
           element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
           prevConfig = false;

           if (element.prevSetting) {
               prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
           }         

           if (options) {
            var customIndex = 0; //define custom variable here
               for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                   allowedProducts = [];

                   /* eslint-disable max-depth */
                   if (prevConfig) {
                       for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                           // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                           if (prevConfig.config &&
                               prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                               prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                               allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                           }
                       }
                   } else {
                       allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
                   }

                   if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                       options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                       element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);

                       if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                           element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                       }
                       element.options[index].config = options[i];
                       index++;
                       customIndex++;  //incremented                     
                   }
                   /* eslint-enable max-depth */
               }
                //add custom code here for preselect if single option avilable
                if(customIndex == 1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                     $('#attribute'+attributeId).val($('#attribute'+attributeId+' option:nth-child(2)').val()).trigger('change');  
                     $("#attribute"+attributeId).prop("disabled", false);
                    },200);                
               }               
           }
       },
   ```
3. Executed deploy commands and cleared flush cache

Comment: I have to use this code but if in drodpdown attribute with swatch image not set  so how to set in first option with image

Comment: Please go to my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257577/magento2-how-to-remove-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-drop-down"

Comment: @RvSingh actually above code is worked for if drop down has a single option, it will select automatically based on selection. may be my solutions won't solve u r problem..

Comment: Thanks for reply but in detail page i have two option for configurable product there i need to remove  "Choose an Option" in drop down menu and have the first attribute value be the top choice