# Change order of "Subtotal" and "Grand Total" amounts in the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, magento-2.2.5

I've got issue because I can't figure out to swap order total brutto with netto. [image]

Look up and check the image. Magento2 maybe by default set Price brutto on the top but I need move price brutto to down. I looked for in module-checkout and magento2 admin panel but I can't find any file to swap this field in the table.

Comment: I've probably found file which is responsibility for view price brutto and netto in Magento_Tax/templates/checkout/grandtotal.phtml but i can't override in  my theme :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution. If someone will have similar issue i write here a solution. If you want change order Excluding tax price and Including tax price you must override file grand-total.html in your theme or module. File path is:
vendor/magento-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html

Comment: I am glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of your totals in the configuration section of the store.

Navigate to: **Admin -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order**

In this section you can reorganise the order of your totals.

Comment: But i can't swap this two rows because they as 1 total order or something like that. I was trying trust me :(

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: I'm using Msg claue theme. I've created Magento_Tax/templates/checkout/grandtotal.phtml and i've made few changes but nothing happened

Comment: Try this file: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/totals.phtml`

Comment: I saw too this file but only contains div with script to connect between knockout.js unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the template path hits to find out which `.phtml` files is used to render the totals? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91235/where-is-template-path-hints-in-magento-2

Comment: Yes, i was trying and even it's turning on at this moment. I saw its totals.phtml but as i told before it contains only knockout.js script which getJslayout(). I've searched in another files but module-checkout even doesn't include tax. I don't know how it works exactly. Maybe magento-tax extends magento-checkout and override cart page. It's really hard to understand what's happening in checkout...

Comment: Try to turn off the theme (use blank) and then use the configuration setting to readjust the order (flush cache etc). If that worked, it would mean that your theme must be interrupting the behaviour of the order somehow, next you would have to find which files are the ones causing the issue.

Comment: I got clean magento2 version next to and in luma theme which is default for magento2 i've seen the same problem. It's really weird because in phtml file order is: first excluding tax and second including tax but view is upside down. I looked for css but i didin't find any styles which modified this template.

Answer (score 0):

you can change order in admin site
 **Admin -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order**

but can't change **Order Total Excl. Tax** and  **Order Total Incl. Tax**
if you won't change it order to **Order Total Incl. Tax** and   **Order Total Excl. Tax** please overide **Magento_Tax** module **web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html**  same as

```
<tr class="grand totals excl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grand totals incl">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: inclTaxLabel"></strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': inclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```