# How to know which file to make changes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, overrides, mini-cart, file

I am new in Magento 2 and I m having very difficulty in finding which templates or blocks to make changes. I know how to override files. I had previously made changes in the theme but still, I can't find an easy solution to locate files in the Magento module.

Can anyone pls explain an easy way to locate files in the Magento theme to override? I m currently working on the Magento Checkout page and Mini cart.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use template path hint to show the file path. This will show all the `.phtml` files used on page view.

To enable template hints, your environment should be development
Note: Do not enable template hint on live website

Use this one to enable template path hints https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91240/31910

Other way to find code is to use well known IDE like PHPStorm etc, that do indexing on codebase and you can search any code easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already know that I m trying to find more easier way to do that.